# Sending push notifications to all users

Tags: parse-platform

This may be a silly question, but I cannot find a way to send push notifications to all users with Parse.com. I can send notifications to specific channels though.

I tried with

```
channels: []
```

but this yields an error.

What's the exact JSON to send push notifications to *all* users? I'm using the REST API.

Comment: So you are trying to use the REST API to push - not Cloud Code? Is Client Push enabled in your cloud code?

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example to send to default [all users] or no channels essentially.

```
{"data": { "alert": "Alert Message", "sound": "somesoundfile", "badge": "Increment" },"where": { "deviceType": "ios" }}
```

You can check out their documentation for other tags they support like parseVersion, appName, appVersion etc etc

**Edit**

To send to all devices you simply don't include the where statement: That was just an example for further customization. Because platforms handle notifications differently and offer different functionalities not all instances are translated. However, here is an example to target all platforms without prejudice:

```
 '{ //not mandatory but just another visual for customizing
    "channels": [
      "Some Channel"
    ],
    "data": {
      "alert": "Alert Message", //not platform specific
      "badge": "Increment", //platform specific iOS
      "sound": "somesoundfile", //platform specific iOS
      "title": "We Pushed to Everyone!" //platform specific Android
    }
  }'
```

Comment: He's not using the website, he uses the REST API.

Comment: @soulshined your code doesn't target all users, it targets iOS users only.

Comment: @kYuZz correct.  You can revise according to your needs

Comment: @kYuZz see my answer for revision. hope this helps you get on your feet

Comment: @soulshined: this is the payload of my request:

    {
        "data": {
            "alert": "Alert Message"
        }
    }

and it just does NOT work. Parse will return the message "Client error response [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request [url] https://api.parse.com/1/push".

Comment: @kYuZz it might help to see where/how the code is implemented to get a grasp of why it might not be working

Answer (score 0):

vb:

```
postString = "{""where"": {""deviceType"": ""android""}, ""data"": { ""alert"": """ + pushMessage + """}}"`
```

c#:

```
postString == "{\"where\": {\"deviceType\": \"android\"}, \"data\": { \"alert\": \"" + pushMessage + "\"}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include "where" and no conditions.

```
{
    "where": {
    },
    "data": {
      "alert": "Willie Hayes injured by own pop fly."
    }
}
```

The full curl commands:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: YOURID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: YOURKEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "Willie Hayes injured by own pop fly."
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```